# my area is not getting printed (abstract using interface)

Tags: interface, abstract-class

I am currently new to interfaces and I encountered this problem regarding my getArea(), I would love if you guys can point out the error on my code

while this is my Triangle abstract class, I am not sure whether I putted the Semi-perimeter(sp) right or not:

````
    private int sideA;
    private int sideB;
    private int sideC;

    int sp = (sideA+sideB+sideC)/2;
    double area = Math.sqrt(sp*(sp-sideA)*(sp-sideB)*(sp-sideC));
    
    public Triangle() {
        
    }
    public Triangle(int sideA, int sideB, int sideC, int sp, double area) {
        this.sideA=sideA;
        this.sideB=sideB;
        this.sideC=sideC;   
        
    }

    public int getSideA() {
        return sideA;
    }

    public void setSideA(int sideA) {
        this.sideA = sideA;
    }

    public int getSideB() {
        return sideB;
    }

    public void setSideB(int sideB) {
        this.sideB = sideB;
    }

    public int getSideC() {
        return sideC;
    }

    public void setSideC(int sideC) {
        this.sideC = sideC;
        
    }
    
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return sideA+sideB+sideC;
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return getArea();
    }

    public void getDetails() {
        System.out.println("\nType: Triangle" + "\nSides: " +this.sideA +", " +this.sideB+", "+this.sideC + "\nPerimeter: "
                + getPerimeter() + "\nArea: " + getArea() + "\ns: "+sp);
    }
}```
````

Comment: You mentioned interfaces but I can't see any interface here as the class declaration is missing. Please provide that along with the error you are getting/ exact problem that you face.  
My assumption would be that you have a interface that declares `getArea()` and `getSp()` methods which you have to implement. In that case, yes, you have done something wrong here as you have added attributes and put the calculation you are supposed to do in `getArea()` and `getSp()` when declaring the attributes.

Comment: Yes @Mushroomator, sorry I was not able to provide you with the sufficient classes due to the warning sign of that my post was full of codes but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Alright, that explains things. Next time leave out all the getters and setters. They are assumed to be there anyway and just focus on what is actually needed to understand the problem in the sense of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) :)